# Bootstrap - 100% width dropdown background but normal content width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm hoping someone can help me out. I've got the following code:

```
<div class="navbar yamm navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown yamm-fw">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <div class="yamm-content">
                                <div class="row"> 
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        Boom 1
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        Boom 2
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Nav Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nav Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nav Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nav Item</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Which works fine. However I want to get the background of the dropdown to be 100% width, however because the dropdown is within the container it will not go full browser width.

You can see an example here:
http://www.bootply.com/9Qy8s3CqMZ
Essentially I want the content to stay where it is, but the grey background to go 100% width like the navigation does.

Anyone help?

Thanks.

-EDIT-
JSfiddle link - jsfiddle.net/on0epsqw/1

Comment: Your example link doesn't work. Please use JSFiddle.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/on0epsqw/1/

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/on0epsqw/3/

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `.container` to `.container-fuid`.

`<div class="container-fluid">`

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/on0epsqw/2/)

**Update**

Change your class `.dropdown-menu` to this:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    background-color:#666;
  }
```

The `top` value should be the height of your navbar.

Furthermore just add the class `.container` to the elements with the class `.yamm-content`.

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/on0epsqw/3/)

Comment: Hello. Thanks. Although I want the backgrounds to be 100% width I want the content to say container width (if that makes sense)?

Comment: The content of your website or the content of the navbar?

Comment: If you see this screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/nbhh6LO.png - Basically I want the content to stay where it is, but extend the background on the dropdown both sides to 100%. hopefully this makes more sense.